# All cells in raster have the NODATA value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I created some vector polygons, added there field `height`, fill it with values. After it using `polygon to raster` converted it to polygon (specified that `value field` to height).

[image]

Than I got rasters.

[image]

But when I called `Viewshed`. I got error: `All cells in raster have the NODATA value`.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use your vector as your DEM. You will need to start with a surface DEM that covers the entire area surrounding your polygons and your points. You should read up on how the viewshed command works. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/using-viewshed-and-observer-points-for-visibility.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is due to your point being on a NODATA cell. How can you do a viewshed if you do not know your height? View sheds are traditionally run on surface DEMs, where every cell has an elevation height. So your input data makes no sense. Suggest you read the Help file to understand the inputs and viewshed concepts.

Comment: how I can create simple DEM from vector that have field `height`?